# Easiest way to combine 6 .csv files into 1 table

Tags: postgresql

I need to merge 6 .csv files into one table (and then 1 .csv). Table has only one column (email). I am very new at this...

Currently I am doing it right this:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
email char(200)

);
```

and then, one by one I Do this, and for some reason instead of 40mb file I get 500mb file.

```
COPY tablename(email) from 'E:\WORK\FXJohn1.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

and I do it 5 more times

```
COPY tablename(email) from 'E:\WORK\FXJohn2.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
COPY tablename(email) from 'E:\WORK\FXJohn3.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
COPY tablename(email) from 'E:\WORK\FXJohn4.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
COPY tablename(email) from 'E:\WORK\FXJohn5.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
COPY tablename(email) from 'E:\WORK\FXJohn6.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

Answer (score 0):

Issuing the command several times is the proper way to load several files.

The size increase is caused by the use of `char(200)` as it fills the 200 characters for each row. You should be using `varchar(200)` as it will store a shorter string without padding it, or event `text` if you don't need to enforce a size limit. See the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html)